# How to change armature to shape to adjust for shape key

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, shape-keys

I have a model with certain shape keys that make it out of shape with the armature (i.e. height change, arm/leg length). Is there a way I can easily have the armature adjust so it lines up with the shape key(s)?